# Salesforce Current Chevron Path Option Not Updating Automatically

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I have a Salesforce Lightning Component that updates the status of an Order.

We make use of the supplied Chevron Path and Record Detail components, however, the status option does not update automatically and we are receiving complaints about it.

Has anyone run into a similar situation and found a method to get around it?

We've tried to force a page refresh to reflect the updates previously, but that didn't work (no refresh occurred), assumedly because of how compartmentalised the lightning component system is.

EDIT: Solved using refresh - as seen in my reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, on retrying it, refreshing appears to refresh the UI of all components, Path and Record Detail included:

Using the line `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` within the aura component helper as found from:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation